# $N$ submodule of $M$ and $N \cong M$ does not necessarily imply that $M=N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $M, N$ be $A$-modules with $A$ being a commutative ring. Suppose that 
$N$ is a submodule of $M$ and also that $N$ is isomorphic to $M$. According
to my understanding this does not necessarily imply that $M=N$. Is this statement
accurate? If yes, at what kind
of cases do we have this phenomenon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take $A = \mathbb{Z}$, $M = \mathbb{Z}$ and $N = 2 \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example: let $A$ be any ring, let $M=\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty B$ for a non-trivial $A$-module $B$, and let $N$ be
$$N=\{(a_i)\in M\mid a_1=0\}.$$
Then $N\neq M$, but the map $f:N\to M$ defined by $f((a_i))=(a_{i-1})$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the half about "When can we expect this?":

A module is called *cohopfian* if every injective endomorphism is surjective. A cohopfian module $M$ will not have any proper submodules isomorphic to $M$.

$M$ will be cohopfian if it is any of the following:

- finite
- Artinian
- Noetherian and injective